# Can't stay in Suspended state on Windows Mobile 6.5 HTC device

Tags: windows-mobile

Our application runs as a kiosk type app on a HTC HD2 Windows Mobile 6.5 device.  When the app is placed in a suspended state using

SystemManager.SetSuspendState(false, false, false);

it periodically will come back out of this state (approximately hourly) for an unknown reason.  We have tried disabling various services (SMS, MMS, third party apps, etc), but still get these unwanted wake up's from the suspended state.  Does anybody know how to determine what is causing a device to leave the suspended state?

I found a developer with a similar issue in this thread,  but the issue was never resolved either.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/229dd6a2-f231-4aeb-ad90-c6995ba155cf/strange-power-state-transitions?forum=windowsmobiledev

Thanks

Comment: In my experience it's almost always the cellular radio. Try turning that off and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly several 'services' that wake up your device. For example it will wakeup periodically to do schedule time housekeeping.

To see what is in the event database you may use my small tool at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/05/13/mobile-development-manage-the-event-db-what-wakes-up-your-device/

The notification api can be used to manage these events: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/03/06/irunatevent/

Be aware that some of the tools re-enter there 'wakeup' events when they are started. The mechanism is described here: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/12/23/windows-mobile-tasker2-runs-and-stops-applications-periodically/

If you provide a list of the 'events db' we can probably find what wakes up the device.

Another source for wakeups may be an incoming cell broadcast or other outgoing network  activity. The GSM modul and WLAN is still powered and my wakeup the device.

You may also just watch for the resume in your kiosk mode app (power notifications: see powerMsglog at https://github.com/hjgode/logging_ce) and immediately send your device into suspend mode.